# Pitch, Yaw, Roll calculation

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

I am struggling with calculation of yaw, pitch, roll rotation of a plane on 3D.
Let's say that I have a plane with 3 points with known coordinates. After rotating this plane in space in 3 ways: roll, pitch, yaw, I will have a new plane. In case, I know the coordinates of these 3 points before and after rotation. How can I calculate roll, yaw, pitch.
Thank you

Comment: Getting three points is not sufficient. For example, if there was a rotation in only yaw, and the pitch and roll remained at $0$, then the two planes would look identical.

Comment: @PavanC. The OP knows more than the plane. They know three points (presumably not collinear) and their images under the rotation. That seems to suffice (assuming an orienation preserving, proper rotation) to identify the rotation. Not sure about pitch-yaw-roll though. Won't you need to be given a frame?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You are right, I agree, if we assume we know the images of each point, we can find the rotation and even a fixed point on the plane. If that's the case, then we can just use the dot product formula. I thought that OP meant we have three points before and then we know three points after, but don't know which is the image of which.

Comment: But the question is lacking context. You should check out [our guide to new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35391/11619). And you should search the site before asking. We have had several related questions already.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen you are correct. my question is I just have one plane in 3D with  coordinates of 3 points ( in this plane). after moving the plane to a new position I want to calculate the rotational movement of this plane ( yaw, pitch, roll), in case I also know the coordinates of these 3 points after the movement

Comment: @Pavan C. Which one do you need to know ?

Comment: Pitch, yaw, and roll may mean different things to different people. I am used to thinking of them in relation to an aircraft, so I need to know which way the aircraft is oriented before I can tell you which motion is pitch, which is yaw, and which is roll. To talk about pitch, roll, and yaw of three arbitrary points on some arbitrary plane is meaningless to me. What do you think these words mean?

Comment: Agree with @DavidK (who most likely knows more about pitch-yaw-roll than I do). I interpret his comment as explaining what I described as needing to give a frame. As in what is the relation of the three key vectors defining the frame: pilot's spine, the direction of the right wing, the main axes of the airplane, to the three given points. Otherwise it is difficult to tell pitch/yaw/roll from each other.

Answer (score 1):

It is a property of rotation in $3D$ that the axis of rotation lies in the plane that is perpendicular to the straight line segment connecting the initial point and the final point, and that passes through the midpoint of this line segment.

So if you have three points $A, B, C$ and their images $A', B', C'$, then you can find the axis of rotation, by finding the equation of the perpendicular bisecting planes to ${AA}', {BB'}$ and ${CC}'$, the intersection of any two of these three planes defines the axis of rotation $a$.

The angle of rotation can be found by projecting $A$ and $A'$ onto a plane that is perpendicular to the axis, and then find the angle between the two projections.

Once the axis of rotation and the angle of rotation are found, then the rotation matrix that describes the rotation that occured, can be found from the Rodrigues' Rotation Matrix Formula, which in one of its forms gives

$ R = {a a}^T + (I - {aa}^T ) \cos \theta + S_a \sin \theta $

where $a$ is the normalized vector pointing along the axis as found above, and the $\theta$ is the angle of rotation.  And,

$S_a = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && - a_z && a_y \\ a_z && 0 && - a_x \\ - a_y && a_x && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

Once the rotation matrix is found, it can decomposed into the product of yaw-pitch-roll rotation matrices.

Normally, yaw rotation is about the $z$ axis, pitch is about the local $x$ axis, and roll is about the $y$ axis.  Combining the three rotations, gives

$ R = R_z(\phi) R_x(\theta) R_y(\psi) $

Define $c_1 = \cos \phi, s_1 = \sin \phi $ and $c_2 = \cos \theta , s_2 \sin \theta $ and $c_3 = \cos \psi , s3 = \sin \phi $, then the above equation is

$ R = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 && -s_1 && 0 \\ s_1 && c_1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && c_2 && -s_2 \\ 0 && s_2 && c_2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c_3 && 0 && s_3 \\ 0 && 1 && 0 \\ -s_3 && 0 && c_3 \end{bmatrix} $

This reduces to

$R = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 && -s_1 && 0 \\ s_1 && c_1 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c_3 && 0 && s_3 \\s_2 s_3 && c_2 && -s_2 c_3 \\ - c_2 s_3 && s_2 && c_2 c_3 \end{bmatrix} $

And further to

$ R = \begin{bmatrix} c_1 c_3 - s_1 s_2 s_3 && - s_1 c_2 && c_1 s_3 + s_1 s_2 c_3 \\ s_1 c_3 + c_1 s_2 s_3 && c_1 c_2 && s_1 s_3 - c_1 s_2 c_3 \\ -c_2 s_3 && s_2 && c_2 c_3 \end{bmatrix} $

By comparing entries on both sides of the equality, we deduce that

$ s_2 = \sin \theta = R_{31} $

which has two solutions $ \theta_1 = \sin^{-1} (R_{32}) $ and $\theta_2 = \pi - \theta_1 $

Looking at the second column,

$\phi = \text{atan2}( R_{22} / \cos(\theta) , - R_{12} / \cos(\theta) ) $

Note that the $\text{atan2}(x,y)$ function that I am using (and which is implemented this way in many programming languages) returns the angle $a$ such that $\cos(a) = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} , \sin(a) = \dfrac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} $.  There are other implementations that flip the order the parameters.

Finally looking at the third row, we get

$ \psi = \text{atan2}( R_{33} / \cos(\theta) , - R_{31} / \cos(\theta) ) $

This shows that its possible to achieve the factorization of $R$ in only two ways.

Comment: The rotation matrix can decomposed into the product of yaw-pitch-roll rotation matrices? An unique solution only?

Comment: No.  It is not unique, if I am not mistaken, in most cases, it can be done in two ways.

Comment: AFAIK in uncountable many ways :(

Comment: AFAIK No.  In a couple of ways only.

Comment: Please check my updated solution, where I explain in detail how to obtain the yaw-pitch-roll rotation angles and matrices.

Comment: In the Rodrigues' Rotation Matrix Formula, what determines $\theta$?

Comment: It is mentioned in the answer where $\theta$ comes from.  It is the angle between the projections of $A$ and $A'$ (or $B$ and $B'$, or $C$ and $C'$) onto a plane whose normal vector is the axis of rotation.

Comment: _"... onto a plane whose normal vector is the axis of rotation"_ -- This plane may be rotated at will, and shows same $A'B'C'$ just rotated.

Comment: The plane we're projecting on can be taken to pass through the origin.  Then, it is well-defined and unique as per the calculated axis of rotation.  Rotating the plane is not the issue here, the issue is the angle between the projections of a point (such as $A$) and its image onto this plane.